# Free module over a countable set

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring. Is $R^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ isomorphic to $R^{\oplus \mathbb{N} }\oplus R^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ as $R$-modules? If so, how do I find an explicit isomorphism?

Edit: I know more or less how the site goes; questions that don't show work generally get downvoted. But in this case, I have no work to show since I don't know how to proceed with this, and anything I might add is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: In future, consider answering the following questions as context: What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N} \oplus \mathbb{N}$ and use that to inform where you send the generators of each copy of $R$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.